# How to train a Hugging face pretrained model using multi gpus?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

Here is the code that loading the pretrained model downloading from Hugging face:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
model6 = UperNetForSemanticSegmentation.from_pretrained("openmmlab/upernet-convnext-tiny",
                                                   ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)  # /upernet-swin-large,upernet-convnext-tiny
model6 = nn.DataParallel(model6, device_ids = [0, 1])
model6 = model6.to(device)
x2 = torch.randn(4, 3, 256,256).to(device)
print(model6(x2).shape)
```

And I get the following errors:

```
RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'input' to have the same device as
tensor for argument #2 'weight'; but device 1 does not equal 0 (while checking 
arguments for cudnn_convolution)
enter code here
```

If I only use 1 gpu, then it works well. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I have changed all the tensors and models to the same device, now another error comes out:
 rch/autograd/__init__.py:130 in  │
│ backward                                                                                        │
│                                                                                                 │
│──────────────────────────────╯
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:1
and cuda:0!